# iOS large file llseek or lseek64

Tags: ios, c, file

I can't find any information how to implement in C module of iOS Xcode project lseek() for large files:

```
llseek()
```

or

```
lseek64()
```

Compilation with:

```
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE 
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
```

has no effect.

How is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use fseeko() and ftello() when seeking to specific 64bit offsets in a file. Pass the file offset as a off_t instead of int and it will work on both 32bit and 64bit systems.

Comment: `fseeko()` and `ftello()` operate on `FILE *` streams.  The question asks about `llseek()` and `lseek64()`, which operate on integer *file descriptors`.